# Can someone explain routing in elastic-search with an example?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I just started working with elastic-search and I need to use the routing in ES but I don't understand how to use it?

I read the routing from elastic-search official references but didn't quite understand though.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/glossary.html#glossary-routing
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html

Comment: What are you trying to do? Using routing to change the way elasticsearch store documents in a shard is pretty specific and you've said that you just started working with the stack.

Comment: even if the article is pretty old, it explains pretty well what routing is: https://www.elastic.co/blog/customizing-your-document-routing